# AS3 externally loaded swf to control stage and MovieClips and their children?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, external, root, stage

I have 2 swf files. One is loaded and loading an externally loaded swf into it.

Here is the code in the first loaded swf: **#1**

```
var logo:Loader = new Loader();
logo.load(new URLRequest("images/Logo.png"));
logo.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadLogo);
function LoadLogo(e:Event):void
{
    addChild(logo);

}

/// The SWF I AM LOADING 

var Beau:Loader = new Loader();
Beau.load(new URLRequest("Beau.swf"));
Beau.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadBeau);

function LoadBeau(e:Event)
{
    addChild(Beau);

}
```

NOW HERE IS THE CODE FOR THE BEAU SWF LOADED: **#2**

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;


bird.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);

function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   ////   I WANT TO BE ABLE TO ADD CODE TO CONTROL MOVIECLIPS 
   ////   AND CHILDREN form this externally loaded swf. How do
   ////   I do that? Below code does not work.

var logo:MovieClip;
var ControlLogo:MovieClip = MovieClip(logo.content);
    ControlLogo.alpha = .3;
```

### }

---

EDIT

ok your code and tutorials are great. I am having major SANDBOX issues now when I make the clip load from an external URL. I am also coding for an ANDROID using FLASH CS5.5. Its not allowing me to use Security.allowDomain("*");

BOTTOME LINE IS THE NEWLY LOADED SWF can not access the PARENT WITHOUT PERMISSION BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO GIVE IT PERMISSION.... using the AIR/ANDROID PLAYER.

Comment: What are you trying to do inside `fl_MouseClickHandler()`? Where does `logo` come from? Is `fl_MouseClickHandler()` getting called at all (try `trace()`).

Comment: Are you using allowDomain inside BOTH of you SWFs? In case it helps, recommended reading: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html

Comment: I tried it both ways. It doesn't work. When loading through AIR on Android it doesn't allow allowDomain. Not sure how to get around this. I may need to start a second post and be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use property `parent`

`parent` gives loader

`parent.parent` gives swf#1

So you can write function as given below

```
function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    var swf1:Object = parent.parent;

    var logo:Loader = swf1.logo;
    var ControlLogo:Bitmap = Bitmap(logo.content); // because logo loads an image
    ControlLogo.alpha = .3;


}
```

make sure that `logo` is not a local variable, but global and public in swf#1

```
public var logo:Loader = new Loader();
```

EDIT:

`logo:Loader`  gets added to  SWF#1. Loads image, so content is Bitmap.

`beau:Loader` gets added to stage. Loads swf (SWF#2), so content is MovieClip.

so now

root is SWF#1

parent of `beau` is SWF#1

parent of SWF#2 is `beau` and parent of `beau` is SWF#1

so for SWF#2, SWF#1 is parent of parent so parent.parent

If you are not creating public variables, you can manage this by using property `name`.

```
var logo:Loader = new Loader();
logo.name = "logo";
...
...

var beau:Loader = new Loader();
beau.name = "beau";
...
...
```

Then anywhere in swf#2

```
var swf1:Object = parent.parent;

var logo:Loader = Loader(swf1.getChildByName("logo"));
....
....
```

For accessing the content it is recommended to use type casting as I have shown

```
var ControlLogo:Bitmap = Bitmap(logo.content); // because logo loads an image
```

so that you can check as shown below and avoid runtime errors

```
var ControlLogo:Bitmap = Bitmap(logo.content); 
if(ControlLogo){

}
```

If you want to so something irrespective of content do as shown below

```
var ControlLogo:Object = logo.content; 
if(ControlLogo && ControlLogo.hasOwnProperty("alpha")){
   ControlLogo.alpha = 0.4;
}
```

Comment: AMAZING! IT WORKED. I feel so grateful for generous people like you on here. If you have time can you explain what the "parent.parent" does? And same with the var Bitmap. Because if I want to load an EXTERNAL SWF THEN would I use a "MovieClip". and if I did and wanted to control the children added in that movie dynamically or hard coded in the swf... then would code would I use? But this is not essential but I would love to know because I am heading in that direction. Thank again soooooo much!

Comment: Also I could not make it A PUBLIC VAR because I am not using a class. I don't know how to use them efficiently yet. Still coming over from AS2.

Comment: Thanks... I have explained it. :)